# Where to search for which sequence of SNPs belong to specific Alleles

Tags: genetics

I'm trying to find more information about a specific Allele, namely the "A1 allele of the DRD2 gene". How can I find more information about this allele, and which SNPs are part of this Allele?

Comment: I doubt this is enough information. Most SNPs have systematic identifiers starting with `rs`. This should be available via the 23andme interface, either as raw data download or browser (I don't have it these days so I can't check web, but it's definitely in the raw data). Once you have that number it should be extremely easy to find studies for which that variant is relevant, along with any phenotypic associations of the variant.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The systematic ID of this allele is rs1800497.

You can use this information to learn a lot about it. [Here is one such resource](https://www.snpedia.com/index.php/Rs1800497), [here is NCBI on it](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/snp/rs1800497), there is a lot more via google.

Those links should have everything you ever wanted to know about this variant.